# Select data from first table and compare it with second one

Tags: mysql, selection

I have a problem in here, I can't understand how this thing works.
So here's the deal:

```
$q= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fruits_list, fruits_have WHERE fruits_list.fruit != fruit_have.fruit AND fruit_list.color != fruit_have.color");
```

Tables:

```
fruits_list
- fruit --- color   -
-   1    -     2    -
-   2    -     3    -
-   1    -     3    -
-   1    -     4    -
---------------------

fruits_have
- fruit --- color -
-   1   ---   2   -
-   1   ---   3   -
-------------------
```

So now this query will remove everything from "fruits_list" that have "1" in "fruit" and "2", "3" in "color".

But I want remove only lanes where both columns are equals. In this example, only 2 lanes should be removed from "fruits_list" and outcome should be like that:

```
fruits_dont_have
- fruit --- color -
-  2    -    3    -
-  1    -    4    -
-------------------
```

So the question is, what should I change in my query?
I hope I did myself clear enough for you to understand.

EDIT:

Ryan E - Simply remove from outcome.

bonCodigo - both are int.

Comment: Remove as in DELETE FROM or simply remove from the output?

Comment: Your table2 doesnot have a col1!!

Comment: are they linked by an id or something?

Comment: Simply remove from outcome.

Comment: What is your col1, col2 Datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would use the SQL `MINUS` set operator, but MySQL doesn't support this yet.

You should be able to do this via a left join with a WHERE to filter out the matches though instead:

```
SELECT fl.*
FROM fruits_list fl
LEFT JOIN fruits_have fh 
   ON fl.fruit = fh.fruit AND fl.color = fh.color
WHERE fh.fruit IS NULL
```

Comment: Working right as it should be. Thank you very much.
And thank you for this small tip with short table names, didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating the two columns withe a separator and then compare as below:

```
     SELECT * FROM fruits_list, fruits_have 
     WHERE CONCAT_WS('@',fruits_list.fruit, fruits_list.color) !=  
               CONCAT_WS('@',fruits_have.fruit, fruits_have.color)
```